# Configure DNS & DHCP Server On Windows Server 2008

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, dhcp

I have installed Windows Server 2008 on my virtual machine (VMware) .

I have to configure a DNS Server and DHCP server .

I should configure one static interface for each server or what ??

When i configuring DNS Server i have a fixed IP and I have to connect to 8.8.8.8(GoohleDNS) at the same time !
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use one static ip on the server and it works fine, I don't feel you need a different IP or Nic for each service.

If you add Active Directory role this will step you through the DNS setup, otherwise adding the DNS role will walk you through the process,  set the NICs DNS entry to the fixed static IP.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725925.aspx